# Connecting Mathematica to Amazon Alexa

Tags: input-devices

Is it possible to connect Mathematica to Amazon Alexa products, so you could  -- for example -- make a queries like

```
amazonAlexa["turn off my lights"]
amazonAlexa["set 10 minute timer"]
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, see this WTC-2015 presentation by Todd Gayley
[“Commanding the Wolfram Cloud” on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JLLFIfeJLiU).

Here you can find the notebook: ["Commanding the Wolfram Cloud" at library.wolfram.com](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/9289/).